# Turn off LG TV with HDMI-CEC (Fire Stick can do it on the same TV)

Tags: hdmi, kodi

I'm trying to turn off an LG TV with Raspberry PI 4, with LibreELEC.

I've seen multiple references saying LG TV does not support standby using HDMI-CEC. And looks like the case with my TV as well. I'm able to turn the TV on using cec-client, but cannot figure out how to turn it off.

I've tried "standby 0", "is" with cec-client, turning off HDMI using `tvservice -o`, without any luck.

I'm curious here.
My Fire Stick connected to the same TV seems to be able to reliably turn on/off the TV. This gives me enough encouragement to try out before giving up, but I don't know what else to look at now.

Does anyone know how Fire Stick would be turning off the TV? Is there a way to "look"/"sniff" how is it working. Anything else I should try with Pi that might work with LG TVs?

Comment: I've voted for this to be closed as this is not really a Pi question, rather a TV one. Saying that, if you can send bytes try sending E0 36 (hex). This is the standard power off sequence.

Comment: Sure. Also, the E0 36 sequence also doesn't work.

Comment: @nisargjhaveri I think you should add the commands you have tried in its complete form.

Comment: Reading https://github.com/olajep/rpi-cecd/issues/7 it sounds like LG do not follow the standards maybe if you can capture the codes  from the Fire box and decode via https://www.cec-o-matic.com/ else it's a hunt for simplink command list:-(

Comment: Have you ever figured out this riddle? I am running into exactly the same problem (with exactly the same frustrating observation that the FireStick manages to turn it on/off)…

Comment: Yes, and the I feel stupid now for not seeing this earlier. The fire tv remote also has IR, and it uses that for controlling the tv on/off and volume, at least for my tv. If you properly block the IR signal, it won't work. It was confusing earlier, as the remote works very nicely even when not pointed to the tv, adding to the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

cec-client which you are using and his library libCEC doesn't support Power Off on LG TV's. You can see the list of functions supported here:
http://libcec.pulse-eight.com/Vendor/Support

On the bottom of the table for LG says:
Supported by all devices except TVs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121789)